# iOS muti-view signup page using MVC

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, ios5

I am new to iOS and am trying to understand the best way to go about MVC.

My signup form has 15 fields (yes, I have to have all those fields!) and I have decided to divide it up into 3 logical screens of 5 fields each. There is going to be 1 user model. In the third and last screen, I will be updating the database. My questions are as follows:

1. Should I create a separate view controller for each view? All 3 views are going to share the same model. My mind tells me that there should be 1 controller for 1 model but then again I am not too sure how best to do it for iOS.
2. If I create 1 controller and multiple views, then will there be any problems hitting the 'back' button? How will the controller know which view to show.
3. Or should I have 1 view and multiple sub-views with 1 controller?

My queries above might sound contradictory because I am confused.

If there is a sample app which shows the best practices for a situation like above, then please provide me with the link to that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be sure to use UITableView when you implement the forms. Either of your three methods could work above, but be sure to use UITableView with UITextField, it'll simplify what you're trying to do.

Comment: if it's the same model, i'd keep it with one VC, and dynamically create your views and add them as subviews during runtime.

Comment: @AmitApollo - If I keep one view controller and have dynamic subviews, then what is the best way to get the back button to work easily? Just putting the subviews in UINavigationController will do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have 1 model which will store fields. Then you can have 3 Controllers for each view (since you might need to do validations depending on fields) which will in turn populate fields into model.

Putting everything inside UINavigationController will let you have back button.

Answer (score 0):

I would have one UIViewController class, but use 3 instances of it which have 3 different views, one for each step.

When the user is done entering their information in one controller, create the new controller and pass along the model to it. The new controller should be able to figure out which step it's on and display the appropriate view.

Answer (score 0):

I would have one UIViewController Class with three views, but once the user enters the information for first view, second view appears. If the information in first view is wrong, it stays in first view.